# EC2 instance - unable to read write files though they exists

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Please help with this strange problem that i am facing with aws EC2 instance. I have launched a EC2 instance & installed `git` to clone my repo. all good untill this, but i am unable to read/write those files though they exists in the same path. observed the same behaviour in Amazon Linux instance as well.

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-54-19:~/win2win$
ubuntu@ip-172-31-54-19:~/win2win$ cd $HOME
ubuntu@ip-172-31-54-19:~$
ubuntu@ip-172-31-54-19:~$
ubuntu@ip-172-31-54-19:~$ cd win2win/
ubuntu@ip-172-31-54-19:~/win2win$
ubuntu@ip-172-31-54-19:~/win2win$ cat myscript.sh
cat: myscript.sh: No such file or directory
ubuntu@ip-172-31-54-19:~/win2win$
ubuntu@ip-172-31-54-19:~/win2win$ ls -lrt
total 28
drwxrwxr-x 2 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Apr  5 09:21 templates
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  792 Apr  5 09:21 sampleIDs
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 2614 Apr  5 09:30 myscript.sh
ubuntu@ip-172-31-54-19:~/win2win$
ubuntu@ip-172-31-54-19:~/win2win$ pwd
/home/ubuntu/win2win
ubuntu@ip-172-31-54-19:~/win2win$
```

Can anyone help.

thanks in advance.

Comment: This happens only with this one repo? What if you clone something else?

Comment: yes.. right, i verified now with a different repo, and it works fine.. Might be the issue with that specific repository

Comment: You might have some odd characters in the filename, try running `ls -l | hexdump -C`